# How to set the path when merging ASS subtitle files in to MKV files

Tags: video, matroska

So I came across this [tutorial for merging ASS subtitle files](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/01/bulk-merge-mkv-ass-subtitle-files/) in to MKV video files. The problem?

How do I set the full path where the files are actually located?

Do I run this command from:

> C:\MEDIA\MULTIMEDIA\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe

Or in the directory that the files are located in?

> D:\My Documents\Desktop\Media\Videos

Comment: That command needs to be run in the directory where the videos are located.